# Do Moment exist for objects in no-gravity enviroment?

Tags: angular-momentum

Imagine a stick with 2x lenght. with mass of m. 
And COG is half way through.  This stick in space. No gravity and friction exist
I pushed the stick from one end point. Do stick start rotating? Or it just go forward without rotation because there is no pivot?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you think gravity can be relevant.

Comment: We are trying to model a the wheel self blancing robot. So we were curious if robot would still work if there is only friction between wheels and floor. And they stay incontact.But there is no gravity.

Comment: @DvijD.C.  If there is no gravity that means there is no pull down from center of mass point. Which  works as a pivot . So no gravity no pivot point. No turn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Newton's laws apply just the same with or without gravity as long as you find yourself a comfy inertial frame to do your experiments. So as long as you're observing from an inertial frame, if you apply a force on a stick from one end, you'll observe it rotate because the force, not passing through the center of mass, would provide a torque about an axis passing through the center of mass, causing it to rotate about the center of mass.

In fact, uniform gravity plays no role in rotating an object because such gravity would accelerate all the parts of the body just the same, which means no contribution to rotational motion.

**Response to Comments**

That's a compelling intuition I have to admit but it's simply not supported by physical principles of motion. If I roughly talk in your language then even if you don't have the force of gravity there is a kind of "imbalance". The imbalance is that you're applying a force that is not uniformly distributed throughout the stick, in particular, it's not distributed symmetrically about the center of mass. An example that should help you change your intuition: put a stick horizontally on a table. The force of gravity is cancelled by the reaction force from table so gravity plays absolutely no role here. Apply a horizontal force on one of the ends of the stick and it'd still rotate if the table is smooth enough.

Comment: Thank you for answer. What is wrong with this logic  "If there is no gravity that means there is no pull down from center of mass point. Which works as a pivot . So no gravity no pivot point. No turn ? "

Comment: @EnesKuz I don't understand what you mean by pivot and what role you think it plays in rotation. As far as the pull of gravity goes, as I said, it acts purely uniformly throughout the body and thus can only possibly produce translational motion, not rotational. If you can clarify what you exactly mean by pivot in terms of physics, I'd be happy to expand my answer to address it.

Comment: " it acts purely uniformly throughout the body and thus can only possibly produce translational motion, not rotational." imagine a stick on a gravity enviroment. throughout the body there is same gravity effect .We can say that through the body there is a force which pulls the stick down . At right side of the stick. I push with Force F in the opposite direction of the gravity. In that part of the body Sum force is G-F . This unbalance is the cause of rotation.

Comment: If there is no gravity and i add the force F then there is still unbalance.But this imbalance would  just make the stick go forward ?

Comment: @EnesKuz Added a response in my answer. It would not just go forward because the imbalance is rotational too (i.e., the distribution of the force you apply at the end of the stick is not uniform about the center of mass of the stick). If you had applied it at the center then that imbalance of forces would just make it go forward without rotating.

Comment: Okay i am fully convinced now . Thank you sir

Comment: @EnesKuz Very glad it helped! :) But please don't call me any names (especially the 'respectful' ones) ;)